# Drives partitioned via server USB caddy not recognized by workstation eSATA (GPT PMBR size mismatch)

Tags: mount, hard-drive, usb-drive, fdisk, sata

We use a USB 3.0 drive caddy (Sabrent EC-DFFN) connected to our Ubuntu 20.04 server for backups. And we are using several make/model 6TB spin drives in daily rotation (one drive per day). Each drive was partitioned on the server (via the USB 3.0 caddy) with *fdisk*. A *GPT* partition was created and then a single *EXT4* file system was created. The server is able to mount and use these drives with no problems.

I was asked to restore a file for review - but not to restore it to the server. So I tried to mount the drive via my eSATA on my Ubuntu 20.04 workstation but the drive won't mount. I'm getting a *GPT PMBR size mismatch*.

Running *fdisk* on the **workstation** shows:

```
GPT PMBR size mismatch (1465130645 != 11721045167) will be corrected by write.
Disk /dev/sde: 5.47 TiB, 6001175126016 bytes, 11721045168 sectors
Disk model: ST6000NM0044    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sde1           1 4294967295 4294967295   2T ee GPT

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Running *parted* on the **workstation** shows:

```
Error: /dev/sde: unrecognised disk label
Model: ATA ST6000NM0044 (scsi)                                            
Disk /dev/sde: 6001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

Running *fdisk* on the **server** shows:

```
 Disk /dev/sdb: 5.47 TiB, 6001175126016 bytes, 1465130646 sectors
 Disk model:                 
 Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
 Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
 I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33550336 bytes
 Disklabel type: gpt
 Disk identifier: B910325B-5CFF-6C46-806A-E95EA72EBFC1

 Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
 /dev/sdb1   8191 1465130640 1465122450  5.5T Linux filesystem
```

Running *parted* on the **server** shows:

```
 Model: SABRENT  (scsi)
 Disk /dev/sdb: 6001GB
 Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
 Partition Table: gpt
 Disk Flags: 

 Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      33.6MB  6001GB  6001GB  ext4
```

Every drive created on the server reports the same *GPT PMBR size mismatch* issue on my **workstation** but the **server** can mount, read, write, in other words, use these drives with no problem.

What am I missing? Is this a eSATA limitation?

**EDIT 2021-04-22**
Per @oldfred, I checked the *fdisk* version on both workstation and server and both both are running version 2.34.

Running *gdisk* on the **workstation** shows:

```
 GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.5

 Partition table scan:
   MBR: protective
   BSD: not present
   APM: not present
   GPT: not present

 Creating new GPT entries in memory.
 Disk /dev/sde: 11721045168 sectors, 5.5 TiB
 Model: ST6000NM0044
 Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
 Disk identifier (GUID): FDBF8804-11D0-44B5-9957-03F5F2D68131
 Partition table holds up to 128 entries
 Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
 First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 11721045134
 Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
 Total free space is 11721045101 sectors (5.5 TiB)

 Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
```

Running *gdisk* on the **server** shows:

```
 GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.5

 Partition table scan:
   MBR: protective
   BSD: not present
   APM: not present
   GPT: present

 Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
 Disk /dev/sdb: 1465130646 sectors, 5.5 TiB
 Model:                 
 Sector size (logical/physical): 4096/4096 bytes
 Disk identifier (GUID): B910325B-5CFF-6C46-806A-E95EA72EBFC1
 Partition table holds up to 128 entries
 Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 5
 First usable sector is 8191, last usable sector is 1465130640
 Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
 Total free space is 0 sectors (0 bytes)

 Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
    1            8191      1465130640   5.5 TiB     8300
```

Comment: Looks like your fdisk did not fully see the gpt. Is this an old version of fdisk? The fdisk tool was the last to be updated to correctly see gpt partitioned drives. Part of reason why gpt has protective MBR with one entry saying drive is gpt, to prevent damage to gpt if tool does not know it is partitioned.  Try with gdisk `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdX` on both systems.

Comment: Thank you. Please see my EDIT above. *fdisk* versions are the same. I provided *gdisk* outputs. Could it be that my workstation chipset doesn't support 6TB? It's an old station running the Intel® P67 chipset. Interesting - it is the EXACT SAME DISK yet the UUIDS being shown by *gdisk* are different.

Comment: Even gdisk on workstation is not correctly seeing the drive. It does not show gpt at all.  My 2006 laptop shows gpt drives, but I do not have any systems with a drive that large. That may be the issue. We have seen older USB to SATA adapters not correctly see either gpt or very large drives.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve had a similar issue in the past. The solution was to run fdisk on it and use `w` to save the existing partition table without any changes.

GPT disks come with a "Protective MBR" (PMBR) which contains a dummy partition that covers as much of the entire disk as is possible, which can result in the size mismatch issue you are seeing.

This has no effect on data stored on the disk; it is there only to guard against old MBR-only disk partitioning tools.

Hope this helps